# Would a Buddha ever lie about lying?

Tags: sotapanna, virtue

Would an enlightened person (stream enterer at the minimum) ever [falsely] make the claim that he is lying?

Comment: Questions about hypotheticals are hard to answer either from scripture or from experience. The double negative (lying that one is lying) is not helping either :)

Comment: what are you getting at with the question?

Answer (score 1):

An arahant or Buddha would never lie, including lying about lying.

However, a Sammasambuddha (a complete Buddha, with the extraordinary ability to teach the masses) may tell the truth about telling different types of truth, that may appear to conflict with each other, but they don't, in actual fact.

A good example is the noble right view vs. the right view with effluents.

> "And what is right view? Right view, I tell you, is of two sorts:
> There is right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions [of becoming]; there is right view that is noble, without
> effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
>
> "And what is the right view with effluents, siding with merit,
> resulting in acquisitions? 'There is what is given, what is offered,
> what is sacrificed. There are fruits & results of good & bad actions.
> There is this world & the next world. There is mother & father. There
> are spontaneously reborn beings; there are contemplatives & brahmans
> who, faring rightly & practicing rightly, proclaim this world & the
> next after having directly known & realized it for themselves.' This
> is the right view with effluents, siding with merit, resulting in
> acquisitions.
>
> "And what is the right view that is noble, without effluents,
> transcendent, a factor of the path? The discernment, the faculty of
> discernment, the strength of discernment, analysis of qualities as a
> factor for awakening, the path factor of right view in one developing
> the noble path whose mind is noble, whose mind is without effluents,
> who is fully possessed of the noble path. This is the right view that
> is noble, without effluents, transcendent, a factor of the path.
> [MN 117](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html)

Comment: you didn’t get the trick of the question:  if one says “I am lying”, is one lying or not lying?  regardless of enlightenedness of one.